# How do I manipulate the data such that it correctly gets mathematically described as stated below?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import csv
import math
inFile = open("Data.txt", "r+")
outFile = open("Analysis.txt", "r+")
temp_data = ()
guess = []
myReader = csv.reader(inFile)
with open("Data.txt", "r+") as reader:
for line in reader:
    temp_data = line.split(',')
    guess.append(temp_data[1])
for line in temp_data:
    for i in line:
        if i.isdigit() == True:
            int(round(temp_data))
inFile.close()
```

**Explanation:**
So far, this is for a school project I am doing in analyzing weather data. Data.txt is just weather data collected from a government website in the correct format and the code above first imports things, open the necessary files, and deals with the data. I need help figuring out how to round all of the float data values into integers with the 'round' function in python and then finding the mean, median, average, and mode for all the data. Analysis.txt is just taking the middle column out of the data.txt and writing it there.

Comment: If ur able to help, please do. It'd make my day.

Comment: Your question is too broad for stackoverflow. But you might want to look into pandas to read the csv and apply a callback function on a specific column on all rows (google `pandas read_csv` and `pandas apply`)

Comment: Hi. Can you use ` three times before and after your code? If you do itthen I'll be able to help you

Comment: @leberknecht Alright, I'll start there, thanks man

Comment: @ClementGenninasca When I press edit, it says "Approve, reject, or improve this suggested edit." and I can't do anything from there. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are a lot of redundant code in your included example, so I am a bit unsure on what you are trying to do, but please see a suggestion below. I am basically iterating through all items in your line, converting them to floats and rounding them.

Changed the `.isdigit()` to a try/except clause for converting to float

```py
guess = []
with open("Data.txt", "r+") as reader:
    for line in reader:
        temp_data = []
        for i in line.split(','):
            try:
                temp_data.append(round(float(i)))
            except ValueError:
                temp_data.append(i)
        guess.append(temp_data[1])
```

To write it to a new file you could do the following

```py
with open("Analysis.txt", "w") as writer:
    for g in guess:
        writer.write(str(g))
```

If you wish to separate the written data, you could do so using the following code (separating with `\n`)

```py
with open("Analysis.txt", "w") as writer:
    writer.writelines('\n'.join(map(str,guess)))
```

Comment: Okay, I understand your code and it seems to work but I don't understand how I would take this data and write it to Analysis.txt. I keep getting "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list." I need the data to be printed in a column in Analysis.txt as well as the median, mean, average, etc for the data in the file.

Comment: Edited my answer to show an example of how to write back to file

Comment: Appreciate your help brother.

I ran the code, seems to work correctly and write perfectly but now i'm getting IndexError: list index out of range. This doesn't make sense since the overall code didn't change at all and we're still calling on the second column from the 3 in Data.txt. Also, the data is in a single structure, aka spaced out or separated by commas (190102190202190302190402190502190602190702190802, etc.)

Comment: Whenever you get a chance, please respond and help me finish. God bless.

Comment: @NeedHELP that probably happens because `temp_data` is empty, since `.isdigit()` returns false for the entries in your data file. Thus when calling `temp_data[1]`, you get an error, since there is no value in the `1` index

Comment: So how do I restructure my code to implement writing to a file? Also, after all of the values are rounded and not floats anymore, I'm not sure I understand why this happens. Shouldn't it just check if the value is a number and return 'true'?

Comment: changed the code now into a try/except that attempts to convert to a float, that should hopefully solve your issue

Comment: You're awesome man, it fixed the code. It all comes as one string in the txt file though. 1.Where am I supposed to insert \n in order to separate the data? 2. And how do would I go about manipulating the data to show mean, median, mode?

After this, I'm done bro and I can finally go onto my 20 quizzes I have to do before the end of the day. THANK YOU SO MUCH, I REALLY NEEDED THIS. :)))

Comment: you are welcome. edited my answer to show how to separate the output data by `\n` - to calculate mean, median and mode i suggest you have a look at the `numpy` and `scipy.stats` packages, they can do this for you. but it is out of scope for this question - probably you can find help by googling.

Comment: if you are happy with the response, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Yes, I will do so. I am very pleased with the response. Final thing, the last bit of code isn't working. The data when sorted by \n is incorrect compared to the data in the original data.txt file. (No, it's not because we rounded. Some values are completely different.) Here's what I mean: https://imgur.com/a/gxiMFGD

I will figure out the calculation part, thanks man.

Comment: Update, I figured out what's happening. I need to delete the first 201 characters every single time the program runs. How would I do this?

Comment: Thanks again, goodbye bro. I completed.